# Chrome extension multiple ports gives Disconnected Port error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension where I'm using two different content scripts. One is loaded in the main page, the other in an external page (which I control) that is loaded in an iframe. The two scripts need to communicate with each other in both directions, which is why I trying to implement the Messaging API.

As far as I understood, it is best to let each page communicate with background.js. Which is what I'm trying to implement. Currently I'm just trying to see if the messages are arriving. But the error I'm getting is:

```
Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
```

It is referring to "page_post.postMessage(msg)" in background.js. Could the problem be that I'm using multiple ports?

menu.js

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "menuport"});
port.postMessage({source: "menu", status: "ready", id: menu_id});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log('MenuJS')
    console.log(msg)
});
```

page.js

```
var page_port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "pageport"});
page_port.postMessage({source: "page", status: "ready"});
page_port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  console.log('PageJS')
  console.log(msg)
});
```

background.js

```
var menu_port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "menuport"});
var page_port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "pageport"});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(menu_port) {
  menu_port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      console.log('BGJS')
      console.log(msg)
      page_port.postMessage(msg);
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(page_port) {
  page_port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked this question again with a different formulation and got an answer quite quickly. The trick is to store the port after connecting. See [Chrome extension - Messaging with multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477679/chrome-extension-messaging-with-multiple-ports/36478118#36478118)

Answer (score 0):

Your `background page` should register `runtime.onConnect` listener once and distinguish different port by `port.name`.

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  if(port.name === "menuport") {
    // menu port logic
  } else if (port.name === "pageport") {
    // page port logic
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I in this case send a message to the "pageport" channel when something comes in from the "menuport" channel. E.g. menuport returns the number 100 and I want to sent this to pageport.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error if I try to post a message to the pageport channel after receiving one on menuport. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This is a little old but I'll add a comment for those who are looking... To communicate across different pages, store the "ports" in the service-worker/background script and use the onMessage listener to determine where to relay the message. If it comes from the menu and needs to go to the page, send it to the page; doing the reverse from page to menu. Just need to make sure that you know which message should spawn off to the other port etc...